# How can I reset/erase a vuex store data?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, local-storage, vuejs2, vuex

In my `/src/store/` folder I have `actions.js`, `index.js`, `mutations.js` and `state.js` which contain the following info

actions.js

```
export default {}
```

index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import state from './state'
import actions from './actions'
import mutations from './mutations'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state,
  actions,
  mutations
})
```

mutations.js

```
export default {
  TOGGLE_LOADING (state) {
    state.callingAPI = !state.callingAPI
  },
  TOGGLE_SEARCHING (state) {
    state.searching = (state.searching === '') ? 'loading' : ''
  },
  SET_USER (state, user) {
    state.user = user
  },
  SET_TOKEN (state, token) {
    state.token = token
  }
}
```

and state.js

```
export default {
  callingAPI: false,
  searching: '',
  serverURI: 'http://10.110.1.136:8080',
  user: null,
  token: null,
  userInfo: {
    messages: [{1: 'test', 2: 'test'}],
    notifications: [],
    tasks: []
  }
}
```

Now, when a user logs in, I keep the state in as

```
this.$store.commit('SET_USER', response.data)
```

Now, when a user logs out, I run my `components/logout.vue` file in which it has the following code:

```
export default {
  data() {},
  created() {
    localStorage.setItem('vuex', null);
    this.$store.commit('SET_USER', null);

    window.localStorage.clear();
    window.sessionStorage.clear();
  }
}
```

But for some reason, the data is somehow persisted.

Comment: `But for some reason, the data is somehow persisted.` Persisted where? in `state.user` or localStorage?

Comment: It is persisted in `state.user`

Comment: I am not sure whats wrong, the same works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zfab6tzp/22/)

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I have a data that is persisted from one week ago. I can't remove it, closed tab, closed browser, restarted pc for a week and I see the storage still.

Comment: Does it change when you login with different user?

Comment: Previously I was using a state as `this.$store.commit('SET_USER')` which updates `this.$store.state.userInfo` this data is still today in my browser, since I can't delete it, I created another state as `this.$store.state.user` which I can commit with `this.$store.commit('ADD_USER')` the latest one can be store and cleared, but the old data is still there today.. Anyway, I am using the lastest for now, but I can't do anything about the old one. I have restarted the pc so many time and still there. I tried to even login via mobile and it logged me automatically, maybe since chrome is synced

Comment: ... my mobile, anyway, I am using the new data so at least it works

Comment: That's funny because it's just an javascript variable. You can just modify it how you want.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to import your store into the logout.vue component?

```
const store = require('path/to/index.js');
```

then in your created method, try

```
store.default.commit('SET_USER', null);
```